# HIbernate Projection or Entire Object

Tags: hibernate, criteria, projection

Which one is better in terms of performance retrieving an entire object through hibenate criteria or using projection and retrieving specific column values

Comment: 1. It depends on your object - how much EAGER loaded fields does it have. 2. It depends on your query - it may still do inner joins for contained objects even if you're using projection for specific column values.

Comment: try to understand query execution plan for your sql queries on underlying DB.You can see amount of time and memory a SELECT statement takes.For example, SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT 1 is much better than SELECT * .To improve performance of your application you need to understand every aspect of hibernate and the DB you are using.

Comment: Thankyou for your answers